# does anyone know how i can get the largest difference between successive inputs?

Tags: c++, math

I got the highest number and the difference but i dont know how to display the largest difference but im not sure where to go from there i just wanting to display the largest difference between the inputs . thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int integers;
    int highest = 0;
    int difference;
        int counter = 0;
    int lastInteger;
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter in integers and enter 0 to stop: ";
    while(cin >> integers)
    {
      if(integers == 0)
      {
          break;
      }
      counter ++ ; 
      if(counter > 1)
      {
      difference = integers - lastInteger;
        cout << difference << endl;
      }
      lastInteger = integers;
    }
    cout << "  The highest number is " << highest << endl;
    cout << "the Differnce is " << difference << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1) Your indentation style is a mess,and makes code reading unnecessarily harder. 2) You didn't even attempt to implement calculation of "_largest difference_". All you do is assign it to the `highest`. SO is not a code writing service. Please come back, once you, at least, tried **something**.

Comment: To compute *"difference between successive inputs"* you need to store previous and current input. once you have the difference, you may compare it with highest difference. As you store every number, you just have to compute the max of `numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i]`.

Comment: there i did something but im not perfect, i thought this website was going  to help me im new to this stuff so dont be so harsh next time im just looking for some help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a new integer variable `maxDifference` to hold the maximal difference and initialize it to zero. Then each time you compute a new value for the `difference`, compare it with `maxDifference` and if it is greater, assign its value to `maxDifference`. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int integers;
    int highest = 0;
    int difference;
    int maxDifference = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int lastInteger;
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter in integers and enter 0 to stop: ";
    while(cin >> integers)
    {
      if(integers == 0)
      {
          break;
      }
      counter ++ ; 
      if(counter > 1)
      {
      difference = integers - lastInteger;
      if (difference > maxDifference)
      {
        maxDifference = difference;
      }
        cout << difference << endl;
      }
      lastInteger = integers;
    }
    cout << "  The highest number is " << highest << endl;
    cout << "the Differnce is " << difference << endl;
    cout << "the maximal differnce is " << maxDifference << endl;
}
```

Please note that I am following your coding style, which in my opinion should be improved.

As an exercise, try to make this work for negative differences too.

Comment: Note: in extreme case `difference = integers - lastInteger;` overflows.

Comment: This code reports the wrong answer when the sequence is ever decreasing  such as `4  2  1  0`  as hinted by "try to make this work for negative differences".

Comment: @chux I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: With sequence `4 2 1 0` , the max difference should be -1, this code could report 0.  On further review, this code does have UB.  The first time `difference = integers - lastInteger;` is called, `lastInteger` value has not yet been initialized nor assigned.

Comment: @chux, I don't see anywhere in the question a requirement to work with negative differences.